# how to reference a variable in an anothere script

Tags: unity

i have a object which sets pickedup = true on collision

```
public class IDCARD : MonoBehaviour
    {
    private bool pickedup = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
       print("k");
        pickedup = true;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    } 
}
```

now i want exit script in an another object to check if pickedup == true on collison
****now what can i do pls  give a brief explanation  with a names i have given****

i have written your code. but i think there is some issues
[image]

Comment: I posted an answer which should answer the question you asked, but I have a suspicion you are asking the wrong question.  Do you want to implement some kind of key/lock puzzle? In that case it might be far easier to have a script on the player gameObject which keeps track of what keys the player collected instead of having that information distributed on other gameObject somewhere else in the world. Or alternatively, create a reference  between the lock and the key and open the lock when the key gets collected.

Comment: Regarding the error in your recent edit: Keep in mind that C# is a case sensitive language.  The type of that variable should be `GameObject`, not `gameObject`.  And `iDCARD` is the reference to a particular IDCARD, while `IDCARD` refers to the class itself, not a particular one. Also, `!=` needs to be written without spaces.

Comment: If you want to reply to someone, it should be done via comments instead of using the text of the post: using the @ before their name, the user is notified, while they're not when using the post text.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you marked the variable "pickedup" as `private`. That means it's invisible for other scripts. When you want to access it from another script, you have to mark it as `public`:

```
 private bool pickedup = true;
```

(or alternatively, you could create a getter-method or a property to access the value of a private variable, but let's stay with the most simple solution for now)

Now, when you want to read that value from another script, you need to know two additional things:

- What game object you want to get the variable from. Remember that there can be many objects in the game which have the same script but with different values.
- What script on that game object contains the variable. Remember that a gameObject can have many scripts, and each of them can have a variable `pickedup` which means something different in the context of that script.

So assuming you have **another** script on **another** gameObject which is supposed to check **this** particular value on something it collided with, you would write it like this:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    // Get the gameObject we collided with
    GameObject other = collision.gameObject;
    // Obtain the IDCARD component of that object
    IDCARD idcard = other.GetComponent<IDCARD>();
    // check if that object actually has an IDCARD component, otherwise you would get a NullReferenceException error
    if (idcard != null) {
        // now we can access the public variable of this script of this gameObject
        if (idcard.pickedup) {
            /*
            ...stuff...
            */
        }
    }
}
```